# Passed an object instead of object's property?

Tags: python, class, oop, object-composition

There is two classes - `Company` and `Project`. `Company` object has property `projects` as list, that should indicate list of `Project` instances that is added to the company
Here is realization of classes and methods to add projects to the company:

```
class Company(object):
def __init__(self, companyname):
    self.companyname = companyname
    self.projects = list()

def show_projects(self):
    print(f"Company projects: {self.projects}")

def add_project(self, name):
    return self.projects.append(Project(name))


class Project(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
```

But when I try to initialize company, then project and add it to company, add add_project returns not `project.name`, but object itself, so i.e. output of this:

```
firm = Company("New")
first = Project("first")
print(first.name)
firm.add_project(first.name)
firm.show_projects()
```

will be:

```
first
Company projects: [<__main__.Project object at 0x00A54170>]
```

Why is it passing not name, but object itself? Can't find out what is missing here.

Comment: Because `self.projects` is a list of Project objects. When you call `Project(Name)`, it creates and returns a new instance of `Project`. If you want the name, you should do `map(lambda x: x.name, self.projects)` and print that.

Comment: Because you call `self.projects.append(Project(name))`

Comment: well, it might be a problem in thise calling as well:D this may be rewritten to pass objet property .name instead of whole object of Project class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`firm.projects` is a list so in `show_projects` when you print it it will be a list of objects. One solution would be to modify `show_projects` to format the list into a comma separated string first:

```
def show_projects(self):
    formatted_projects = ','.join([p.name for p in self.projects])
    print(f"Company projects: {formatted_projects}")
```

Comment: Thank, that works. But forward question - can i somehow append to the list not whole object of class Project, but only it's name property?

Comment: Maybe something like:

    def add_project_name(project):
        self.project_names.append(project.name)